# How to create nested groups using Eclipse Collection's Multimap?

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

I have read [Map vs. Multimap](https://medium.com/javarevisited/map-vs-multimap-6ea2b1b79de5) with great interest. *Multimaps* are indeed a commonly used concept for which there's no standard JDK type.

As I am still exploring the Eclipse Collections library, I do have some questions about the usage of Eclipse Collection's *Multimaps*.

First, what is the most elegant way to create nested groups using Eclipse Collections?
Using standard Java Streams, it is merely using another *groupingBy* Collector as downstream.
This allows you to create nested groups as deep as you'd like.

```
Map<K1, Map<K2, List<V>>> collect = List.of(V, V, V, ...).stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function<V, K1>,
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function<V, K2>,
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    );
```

Can you achieve something similar using Eclipse Collections?

---

As a follow-up question, I could not find a *collect* method to operate on a complete group, something like:

`Multimap.collectMultiValues(Function<? super RichIterable<V>,?> function)`

As I am relatively new to this API, this will probably exist but in another form.
Until I learn of a more elegant solution, I rely on the following methods:

1. `Multimap.keyMultiValuePairsView()`
2. `Multimap.forEachKeyMultiValues(Procedure2<? super K,? super RichIterable<V>> procedure)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Collections works with Java Streams. There is a [`Collectors2`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html) utility class in the library which returns specific types from the library like `Multimap`. The following code will group a `List` of fruit Strings by the first letter and then by the length of the fruit. There are `Collectors` for mutable and immutable types, so I am showing both below.

```
List<String> fruit = 
        List.of("apple", "apricot", "banana", "blueberry", "clementine");

Map<String, MutableListMultimap<Integer, String>> groupedMutable =
        fruit.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        each -> each.substring(0, 1),
                        Collectors2.toListMultimap(String::length)));

Map<Object, ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, String>> groupedImmutable =
        fruit.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        each -> each.substring(0, 1),
                        Collectors2.toImmutableListMultimap(String::length)));

Assertions.assertEquals(groupedImmutable, groupedImmutable);
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("apple"), groupedMutable.get("a").get(5));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("apricot"), groupedMutable.get("a").get(7));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(), groupedMutable.get("a").get(10));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("banana"), groupedMutable.get("b").get(6));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(), groupedMutable.get("b").get(8));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("blueberry"), groupedMutable.get("b").get(9));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("clementine"), groupedMutable.get("c").get(10));
Assertions.assertEquals(List.of(), groupedMutable.get("c").get(5));
```

There are no Eclipse Collections specific methods for multi-level grouping. We thought Java Streams handled this fairly well, and it was better to provide interop than an alternative.

For the second part of your question (which could be a question on its own), I think the method you might be looking for is [`collectKeyMultiValues`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/Multimap.html#collectKeyMultiValues(org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function,org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function)). I would need to see a code example to confirm if it is suitable for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: With the answer you've posted, I currently do not have the need anymore for such a *collectMultiValues* method.
When I encounter a use case in the future, I will post a separate question with the necessary code samples.
Thanks again for the swift response.